# Bitbucket not displaying the git commit properly, due to Windows/UNIX commit differences

Tags: git, bitbucket, osx-yosemite

I made a git commit using Yosemite on my Macbook7.1 (mid-2010). Before this I used PC and git and BitBucket worked like a charm, without any errors like this ever happening.

I have simplified the issue so I can reproduce it to you more easily. I have typed just a single space in my file and commited this to bitbucket. After this , when I look at the commit diff on BitBucket on the internet repository, I am getting the diff that completely differs to the actual state of the file (it should just have a single space in it). Here is the diff as displayed on bitbucket:

http://pastebin.com/cbiKPmzF

To clarify more - first of all - the line:
var parameters:Array = game.coasts.getDockInitializationParameterSet(0) wasn't touched at all!!!!!!
Second of all it says that it is added same on line 14. Again, it is not touched at all!!! the blank line is not even marked, but is displayed.
Does anyone know something about this completely weird and ALIEN behaviour of bitbucket?????? And how to mend this? I highly doubt it and am planning to give up on this combination of development (action script 3.0 on yosemite using bitbucket for git). I am getting all kinds of strange behavior on git using Mac that never happened to me on PC.

Comment: Mmmm... line ending changes.  Yum.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the style of CRLF in SublimeText (which is my editor of choice) to UNIX (View -> Line endings -> Unix). Now commiting displays proper changes. Gohd! Thanks.

Comment: You can fix this in git too.  https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: I actually tried this, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the style of CRLF in SublimeText (which is my editor of choice) to UNIX (View -> Line endings -> Unix). Now commiting displays proper changes.